# Moving the "active" class in a dropdown menu to the users current page

Tags: jquery, css, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-5

So i thought i would give the Foundation framework a go and the first problem i run into is class="active" in a dropdown menu.

What i want is the class to apply to the page link (in the dropdown list) the user is currently viewing, if this is easily done any help would be appreciated.

I have scoured the Foundation Docs and the world wide web and gotten nowhere unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are tying to achieve is usually done by the backend or my your front-end MVC (like angular or backbone) by testing where you are and printing an 'active' class on the right link.

Foundation isn't an MVC framework. It simply helps quickly developing some HTML, CSS, and JavaScript by leveraging their modular, pre made code.

That being said, if you wanted to achieve this purely on the front-end, you would need to create a function that parses your URL, finds the link with that matching URL, and add a class of 'active' on the matched on.

Comment: Damn.. I was hoping there would be a built-in function or script to do this. Not to worry, thanks for your time. I'll be adding some basic PHP to the site soon anyway so i'll sort something out there.